# Child subscribing to parent's events

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

It is trivial in Blazor to subscribe a parent control to child's events: in the child, I just declare

> [Parameter] Func OnClick { get; set; }

and assign a parent's method to OnClick in the child control markup. However, how can I achieve the opposite? I want the child to react to events from the parent control. So far I am just plain calling child methods from the parent - is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an event on the parent component which can be handled by subscribers (for instance, a child component) when the event is raised.

### On parent component

Define an event handler, say, StateChanged

```
public event EventHandler StateChanged;
```

### Raise the event from code on the parent

```
StateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

### On the child component

```
// Subscribe to the event defined on the parent component
protected async override Task OnInitAsync()
        {
            ParentComponent.StateChanged += OnStateChanged;
}

// Dispose of the component
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            ParentComponent.StateChanged -= OnStateChanged;
        }

        void OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => Call_A_Method_That_Do_Something();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: doesn't doing this require the event on the parent to be static? otherwise you need a reference to the parent component in the child, which may be tricky. also aren't static events a terrible idea?